# How to display toolbars, navigations pane, ribbon, and menus for specific users in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have different access levels setup for a database.
Depending on the level of access, the navigation pane will be locked, the ribbon menus may be limited, etc.

In testing, when I change my access level, I found in some cases, not all of the commands work.
The user has to close and reopen, then it will display correctly.

```vb
Private Sub ToolBars()
    Dim AccessLevel As Integer
    Dim UserALevel As Integer

    UserALevel = [Forms]![frmLogin]![AccessLeveltxtbox]

    AccessLevel = DLookup("AccessLevelID", "tblUserNew", "AccessLevelID=" & UserALevel)

    If UserALevel = 1 Then
        Application.SetOption "Show Hidden Objects", True
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowFullMenus") = True
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowShortcutMenus") = True
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBuiltinToolbars") = True
        DoCmd.LockNavigationPane False
        DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
        DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Status Bar", acToolbarYes
    Else
        Application.SetOption "Show Hidden Objects", False
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowFullMenus") = False
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowShortcutMenus") = False
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBuiltinToolbars") = False
        DoCmd.LockNavigationPane True
        DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
        DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Status Bar", acToolbarNo
        DoCmd.NavigateTo ("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *I have found in some cases, not all of the commands work.* -- this is rather vague, unfortunately. Can you be more specific which commands don't work, and when?

Comment: Some of these properties may only be available when *first* opening database and remains from last settings. Dynamic window adjustments on the fly may not be supported.

Comment: Hopefully, your Access app is split with many UI frontends to single backend data source where each user uses his/her own copy. If so, distribute different design versions to users by levels. Of course this may entail development on multiple app versions but hopefully development changes are rare. You could use same code to automate needed settings.